# using value of current row value for table update

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my table I have around 120 url(primary key). and now I added one more column `hash` which takes hash values like this

```
$hash = md5($url);
```

I want to remove url as primary key (I did it) and set hash as primary key.

Currently when I try to make hash as primary key, say dublicate entry error. Because all 120 entry for hash is empty.

So I want update my table such that hash should be set to hash=md5(url).

My try:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'mysql');                
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())    
    {    
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();    
        return;    
    }    
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT url from frrole_cateogry_article");    
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_array($result))    
    {    
        $url = $row['url'];
        $hash = md5($url);
        $update = "UPDATE table frrole_cateogry_article set hash='".$hash."' where url = '".$url."'";           
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$update))    
        {    
            //die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); 
            echo "error";
        }       
    }           
?>
```

error message with `die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));` is

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table frrole_popular_article set hash='3402a8ee11df088cd4e4a270dacbcc98' where u' at line 1
```

But it give error echo `error` message.

What is wrong?

Comment: Why have you commented out `mysqli_error($con)`? That could tell a lot

Comment: Why not set an Auto ID column as primary key and then change all your hashes?

Comment: show your error message...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: it says 'Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table frrole_popular_article set hash='3402a8ee11df088cd4e4a270dacbcc98' where u' at line 1'

Comment: I think no need of `table` in `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: That's correct @user007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE frrole_cateogry_article SET hash=md5(url)
```

That's it. No loops and no selects are required. This will set `hash` on every row to be `md5` of its `url` in the same row.

Comment: thanks but it says ` check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table frrole_popular_article set hash=md5(url)' at line 1` even same in phpmyadmin

Comment: See the update. Remove the word "TABLE" from the query. Its not required for an Update query

Answer (score 1):

MySQL also supports [`MD5`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

You can do something like:

```
$update = "UPDATE frrole_cateogry_article set hash=md5( url_field )";
```

This statement updates all the record urls to md5 hash. No while loop is required.

Comment: This will require the unnecessary loop to still be there. It can be done with a much simple one liner than requiring a loop and select

Comment: Oh yes. My intention was to suggest the same. I missed it. Updated my answer.